# Font for Access Key Code

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm working on a project that will mail out access codes. Yes, using physical snail mail. The recipient needs to be able read the code and accurately type it into a web form. The codes consist of seven characters including upper case A-Z, lower case a-z, and digits 0-9.

My question is how to communicate exact characters, keeping in mind that I might have a number 0 immediately next to the letter O. A code may also contain one, but not the other. I'm also concerned about i vs I vs l vs 1... and those are four different valid characters.

What fonts can I use that will clearly distinguish these? What are tests I can use to check the font? Are there other sets of similar character glyphs I might be missing? Is there anything else that I can/should be doing to make sure these are readable in an accurate way?

Comment: What is the feasibility of eliminating uppercase `O` from the code? Are your customers likely to give up after hitting a `0` instead of uppercase `O`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for programming fonts.

Character differentiation can be crucial when programming; these are fonts that are designed specifically with this sort of thing in mind.

**Consolas** is a very popular choice. Here's what those characters look like:

[image: Consolas]

Here's a huge thread on programming fonts over at Stack Overflow: [Recommended Fonts for Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4689/1832306)

---

I don't want to change your criteria, but have you considered only distributing key codes that omit ambiguous characters? This is not an uncommon practice. For example, in the US all vehicles are required to have a VIN. As a measure of error prevention, they follow this rule:

> does not include the letters I (i), O (o), or Q (q) (to avoid confusion with numerals 1 and 0)<sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number)</sup>

When the user inputs they key code, you could check for any of the invalid characters and have some sort of pop-up with a message like "*Oops! You entered an I. Are you sure that's not a 1?*"

Comment: It is very tempting (and would be fairly simple) to remove all six of those character glyphs from my alphabet, even if it does cut my key space in half (and thus reduce the security by an equivalent amount). And looking at the sample, I think I can just remove the upper case O. Everything else there is completely unmistakable.

Comment: Hmm... quick test says I also need to remove lower-case L.

Comment: I'll run some numbers tomorrow, and I'll accept this then if an alphabet size of 60 (no O or l) still meets my goals --- I want the rarity of a real match (in terms of avg # of guess required to get a hit) to be better than 1 in 1 billion, based on the key size and expected population size

Comment: Got impatient: the rarity comes to a little over 1 in 933 million. I think that will have to do, though, and even worse I'll lose another character: I'm leaning towards actually using Courier (for guaranteed availability) and dropping the upper O, lower L, and numeral 0.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I see what you mean about `l`, definitely very similar to `1` (I updated my post to include the glyph, not sure why I didn't in the first place). Good luck with it!

Comment: You still get the accept, for suggesting paring down the alphabet. Once we can do that, font choice becomes less important.

Answer (score 2):

Can't go wrong with **Andale Mono**.

## Andale Mono

[image]

Changed my answer from *Courier* to **Andale Mono**

Comment: lower-L still looks like a one. numeral 0 and upper O could still confuse.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I can see your point on the `O` & `0`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Changed my answer to Andale Mono. `O` and `0` are distinguished, as well as the `1` and lowercase `l`.

Comment: Would still need to drop the upper case O, but now it's one character better than consolas. I'm inclined to still drop the lower case L, too, because it's just ugly. I could see people going, "What in the world is that?". Also, Consolas is already installed on the machine where this will run, where I'm pretty sure I'd have to setup Andale Mono special.

Comment: Actually, I think I will go with Courier, in case we ever get to e-mail these. I **know** that will be available on any target system. Key space now down to 59 :(

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Ah, people may mistake the `O` for an `0` if they haven't seen the zero?

Comment: That's the idea.

Answer (score 2):

**OCR-B** was designed for a similar purpose.  All characters are easy to distinguish both by the human eye and for optical character recognition.

[image]

OCR-B replaced a previous font called **OCR-A** which exaggerated even more the differences between similar letters, at the expense of making it less pleasant for humans to read.  You might have seen these on bank documents, cheques, pay slips etc:

[image]

**Think about base-32 encoding**

But you should also think of it in another way - why not encode your access code using [Base 32 (crockford version) encoding](http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html)?  This is an encoding which excludes the letters I, L, and O to avoid confusion with numbers, and also excludes the letter U to prevent accidental obscenity in English.  Then you can use just about any font.

Comment: Even in OCR-B, the letter O and digit 0 *could* be confused if you don't know the font and don't have both available to compare.

Comment: Indeed.  I'm surprised they didn't use a dotted or slashed 0.

Comment: An interesting feature of uppercase or numeric OCR-A, which OCR-B lacks, is that every character includes unique features in both inked and non-inked areas. Errant marks or voids could render an OCR-A character unreadable, but only a combination of errant marks and voids could turn one uppercase or numeric OCR-A character into another (though I do find it curious that the difference between the top of the "B" and "P" is pretty slight).

Answer (score 1):

A simple test is to go to MyFonts.com and type in a string for the sample text of all the similar characters and start looking.

For zeros, look for a font with a slashed-zero. The I/l/1 issue is a bit trickier, though.